# NodeJs: How to make consecutive http requests on the same connection

Tags: node.js, httprequest

I need to connect to a custom XML service that have following requirements:

The first http request to the service must be made to the **Login endpoint**, with the header field **"Name"** containing the user we want to connect. In response we get a **"Digest"** header field containing a challenge that we must use to compute a value to send with the following requests.

The following requests **must be made on the SAME CONNECTION** and sending a "Digest" header containing the previously computed value based on the response.

If we fail to do so, the server ends the connection with error.

I've tried using an http agent with keepAlive=true and maxSockets=1 but I can't get a response from the second request. (If i disable the agent I get a response but the request is ended from the server because it's made from a different connection.

Appreciate any help... here is my code:

```
var http = require('http');
const keepAliveAgent = new http.Agent({ keepAlive: true, maxSockets: 1 });
var docxml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252'?><document><docitems></docitems></document>";

var loginHash = function(user, password, digest) {
    result= digest+password+user;
    return result.toString();
}

var loginOptions = {
    host: '10.190.22.1',
    port: 2261,
    path: '/Login',
    agent: keepAliveAgent,
    headers: {
        'name': 'JOSE'
    }
};

req1 = http.get(loginOptions, function(res1) {

    procDigest = loginHash('JOSE', 'ROCHA', req1.res.headers.digest);
    console.log('Digested: ' + procDigest);

    var insertOptions = {
        host: '10.190.22.1',
        port: 2261,
        path: '/PostSomething',
        method: 'POST',
        agent: keepAliveAgent,
        headers: {
            'Digest': procDigest
        }
    };

    var req2 = http.request(insertOptions, function (res2) {
        console.log('Request2 Headers: ' + JSON.stringify(req2.res.statusCode));
    });
    req2.on('end', function (){
        console.log('Request2 Headers: ' + req2.res);
    });
    req2.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log('Error: ' + e);
    });

    req2.write(docxml);
    req2.end();

});
```

Comment: Did you try adding a `res1.resume()` to drain the response from the first request?

Comment: Thanks @mscdex that did solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a `res1.resume();` will allow the response for the first request to be drained/discarded so that the second request can be made on the same socket.